Bijectivity of a linear map between symmetric polynomials of even degree
Let $\mathfrak S_n$ be the symmetric group of permutations of $n$
letters and let $S = \sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak S_n} \sigma$ be the
symmetrization operator.
Let $\Lambda_n^r$ be the vector space of symmetric polynomials in $n$
variables $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of (homogeneous) degree $r$.
Consider the map
$$
\Psi: \Lambda_n^r\to\Lambda_n^r\\
f \mapsto S \cdot f(x_1, x_1 + x_2, \dots, x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n),
$$
where the symmetric group acts by permuting variables.
Computational evidence suggests that, for $n\geq 1$, this map is
bijective if and only if $r$ is even, or $n=1$, or $r=1$.
How could we prove this?

Notes:
Maybe it helps to generalize the question as follows.  We could write the map as
$$
f\mapsto S\cdot f(M \mathbf x)
$$
where $\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots, x_n)^T$ and $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.  In the special case above,
$$ M = \left(\begin{matrix}
1      & 0     &\dots & 0\\
1      & 1     &\ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots &       &\ddots & 0\\
1      & \dots & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Which matrices $M$ make the map bijective?  Note that bijectivity is preserved when permuting the columns or rows of $M$, because $f$ is symmetric and because we symmetrize $f(M\mathbf x)$.
Experimentally, for small $n$, there are many matrices that make $\Psi$ bijective.  In fact, there are also many matrices that make $\Psi$ bijective if and only if $r$ is even.
In general, the map does not map characters to characters, for example, for $n=2$ and $r=6$.

Looking at the sequences of determinants, we have the following table, the first row corresponding to the case $n=1$, the first column corresponding to $r=1$:
$$
\begin{array}{llllllll}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & -4 \\
12 & 40 & 0 & 560 & 0 & 26880 & 0 & -49674240 \\
60 & 1200 & 0 & -1128960 & 0 & -682795008000 & 0 & 72912553997374586880 \\
360 & 50400 & 0 & -23897825280 & 0 & -3663070894604943360000 & 0 & -1322279213561113068120489525050867712000 \\
\end{array}
$$
Apparently, for $n=2$ we get, up to sign, $2^{\lfloor\frac{r}{6}\rfloor+1}$ for even $r$.  It seems that the entries in the row for $n=3$ are nicer if we divide by the corresponding Bernoulli numbers. For $r=1$ we seem to get the order of the alternating group.  Finally, for $r=2$ and $n>1$, the determinants seem to be $(n+2)!(n+1)!/72$.

You are working in characteristic $0$, right?

Yes! (sorry, "yes!" has only four letters, which is too short for mathoverflow, but I didn't notice)
